# Exporting VMs with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

New to VBox and can't seem to find any documentation on this that is friendly for newcomers. I have set up a guest VM on one host (my laptop), and now I want to move that VM to another physical computer which will also have VBox installed on it.

How do I accomplish such a transfer? Is this the same as making the VM a "virtual appliance"?

Comment: VirtualBox has an Export Appliance feature under the File menu. I would use that since it will prompt you to automatically regenerate the MAC address of the NIC. I do this from time to time when i'm setting up a new Devel environment and want to have that same instance running on another computer host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to copy the VM, just copy the Folder which contains the VM Files to your other computer and use it there.

If you want to acces the version on your Laptop from your computer, I would suggest just setting up a network and make the files available thru the network to your other computer.

Comment: Does that hold up even if they are different OSes? Please see my comment to Paperlandtern.

Comment: @zharvey yeah. no prob, did that already.

Answer (score 0):

The last time i moved a machine from one computer to another i just copied the folder that houses the Virtual machine to a external drive, and copied it down to the new machine, pointed VBox to it, boom, came right up. No export necessary.

Comment: what if they are two different OSes? My laptop is Windows and my other computer is Ubuntu...